# Matlab zoom or pan an image while 'Clipping' is 'off'

Tags: matlab, clipping, zooming, pan

I try displaying image with non standard aspect ratio (width>>height) in my GUI.
But when I zoom-in the image is clipped to the original axes position. I've managed to solve this problem by setting the 'Clipping' property to 'off'. But now for some reason the pan and zoom tools are only active while the mouse hovers over the initial position of the image (the position it had before I zoomed in).

Here is a piece of code for demonstration (I'm using Matlab 2011a, but also noticed the problem in other versions):

```
I = repmat(imread('cameraman.tif'), [1 20]);
figure, 
h=imshow(I);
set(h,'Clipping','off')
```

(Just run those lines and try zooming in once or twice. The zoom/pan tools will only work in the area where the image initially was.)

Is there a way of zooming in without clipping the image, and yet getting the pan and zoom tools to work all over the enlarged image?

Comment: Do you have an example that we can test? See http://sscce.org/

Comment: Yes, just entered one above.